# UIView animateWithDuration strange behaviour, jump to opposite position and the beginning of animation and move back

Tags: ios, animation

I'm developing a iOS guitar tuner, there is a pointer which is moving around center of a view, shows if a guitar string is higher or lower than standard  pitch position.

Sometimes the pointer jump to the opposite target position of an animation just at the beginning of animation, then goes back from that point to the beginning position of animation.

I'm not using xib or Auto Layout, just custom UIViewController and views. The animation takes longer than my trigger interval, so I need to cancel previous animation first, then start the new one. Here is my code:

```
CGPoint p = ((CALayer*)[self.pointerView.layer presentationLayer]).position;
[self.pointerView.layer removeAllAnimations];
self.pointerView.layer.position = p;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    CGFloat pointW = self.pointerView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat pointH = self.pointerView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat x = width * 0.5;

    // calculate x 
    if(cents - centerCents > self.halfWidthCents) {
        x = width - pointW * 0.5 - margin;
    } else if(centerCents - cents > self.halfWidthCents) {
        x = pointW * 0.5 + margin;
    } else {
        x = width * 0.5 + (cents - centerCents) / self.halfWidthCents * width * 0.5;
    }
    self.pointerView.center = CGPointMake(x, pointH * 0.5);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Here is an gif image of this behavior 
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQPwk.gif)

The pointer should move from center to left, but it jumps to the right then move back to center for several times, at last it seems to understand and move left.

Does any one face this kind of problem ? Or is there anything I can do to simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you list is the entire content of the method than I would remove the following and run your app again.

```
CGPoint p = ((CALayer*)[self.pointerView.layer presentationLayer]).position;
[self.pointerView.layer removeAllAnimations];
self.pointerView.layer.position = p;
```

Why? Because the pointerView layer's position is also the pointerView's center and here you are setting the pointerView layer's position, just before your animation call. This could be the reason you get the *jump* before the view's animation.

I have cleaned up the view animation call. It is easier to read when you do your calculations outside of the animation block.

```
// calculate x
if(cents - centerCents > self.halfWidthCents) {
    x = width - pointW * 0.5 - margin;
} else if(centerCents - cents > self.halfWidthCents) {
    x = pointW * 0.5 + margin;
} else {
    x = width * 0.5 + (cents - centerCents) / self.halfWidthCents * width * 0.5;
}

CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(x, pointH * 0.5);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{

                     self.pointerView.center = newCenter;
} completion:nil];
```